# (Where) is determining the mixing time of an implicitly defined graph in the polynomial hierarchy?

Tags: graph-theory, quantum-computing, polynomial-hierarchy, markov-chains

Consider an implicitly defined graph; for example, let $G$ be a finite group generated with $n$ generators as $\langle g_1,g_2,\ldots g_n\rangle$ and let $\Gamma$ be the Cayley graph of $G$ under these generators.

We can ask how long $m$ of a discrete-time random walk it takes along the Cayley graph, starting say from the identity $e$, such that the distribution of the vertex so reached is within a total variation distance $\delta$ of less than $\epsilon$ from the stationary distribution $\pi$.

Under appropriate promises, where in the polynomial hierarchy is it to determine $m$ given $G=\langle g_1,g_2,\ldots g_n\rangle$?  For example if we concern ourselves with multiplicative error, is this amenable to Stockmeyer counting?  For additive error, is it even *in* the polynomial hierarchy?

This is related to the spectral properties of $\Gamma$, in particular to the spectral gap of the adjacency matrix of $\Gamma$. Under what conditions is even learning this gap in PH? My hidden motivation is when is it in BQP?

Comment: Why the promise? Even if the mixing time is poly(|G|), that's still at most exponential in n (assuming the generating set is not much larger than it needs to be) which can still be represented by poly(n) bitsize.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow You're right!  I totally missed that point and guessed that we had to actually *do the $m$-length walk* to have any chance to verify, which is prohibitive if $m=O(\vert G\vert)$, but of course that might not actually be required.  Perhaps the more relevant promise is on the accuracy $\epsilon$.